# Migration problems from play 2.04 to play 2.1

Tags: flash, session, request

I am migrating my app from play 2.0.4 to play 2.1.0.
Play 2.1 doesn't recognize flash, session  or request in views, giving compilation error

How to represent the following  code from play-2.0.4 in play-2.1.0

A. flash

```
@if(flash.contains("success")) {
        <p class="success">@flash.get("success")</p>

        }
```

B.session -----

```
@if(nav == "signup" && session.get("sitetype")=="public")
```

C. request

```
var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Chat.chat(username).webSocketURL(request)")
```

Error log

```
[error] /Users/abhijitbasu/SampleApps/smartex-app/app/views/chatRoom.scala.html:120: not found: value request
[error]             var chatSocket = new WS("@routes.Chat.chat(username).webSocketURL(request)")
[error]                                                                               ^
                              ^
[error] /Users/abhijitbasu/SampleApps/smartex-app/app/views/login.scala.html:16: not found: value flash
[error]         @if(flash.contains("success")) {
[error]             ^
[error] /Users/abhijitbasu/SampleApps/smartex-app/app/views/main.scala.html:159: not found: value session
[error]                                     @if(nav == "signup" && session.get("sitetype")=="public") {
[error]                                                            ^
[error] /Users/abhijitbasu/SampleApps/smartex-app/app/views/mediainsight.scala.html:109: not found: value session
[error]              ajaxpage(rootdomain+'@routes.Chat.chatRoom(session.get("firstname") + ' ' + session.get("lastname"))', 'contentarea')
[error]                                                         ^
[error] /Users/abhijitbasu/SampleApps/smartex-app/app/views/signup/form.scala.html:39: not found: value flash
[error]                     <p class="error">@flash.get("error")</p>
```

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

adding appdendency and importing template helped

val appDependencies = Seq(
       javaCore, "org.apache.commons"       % "commons-email"           % "1.3.1"

```
)
```

val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .settings(
templatesImport ++= Seq("play.mvc.Http.Context.Implicit._")
 )

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I have a solution to section C.

At the top of chatRoom.scala.html add `@(username: String)(implicit request: play.mvc.Http.Request)`

This will bring an error, because the request needs to be passed. You're probably calling code similar to `ok(chat.render(username));`, change it to `ok(chat.render(username, request()))`;

In plugin.sbt, add the line: `javacOptions += "-Xlint:deprecation"`